# How can i establish rpc properties with the datasource type DB in Corda community edition?

Tags: database, rpc, corda

To establish an RPC connection in the community edition we need to specify the rpc username, password and permissions but when we are integrating external database like MySQL and change the datasource type from INMEMORY to "DB" it does not allows to give user properties.

these are the settings I am using in my node.conf

```
security = {
  authService = {
    dataSource = {
        type = "DB"
        passwordEncryption = "SHIRO_1_CRYPT"
        connection = {
            jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"
            username = "root"
            password = "password"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        }
    }
    options = {
        cache = {
            expireAfterSecs = 120
            maxEntries = 10000
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand your question, but database setup in `node.conf` is separate from RPC user setup in `node.conf`:
**Database (PostGres in my case)**

```
extraConfig = [
        'dataSourceProperties.dataSourceClassName' : 'org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource',
        'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.url' : 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres',
        'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.user' : 'db_user',
        'dataSourceProperties.dataSource.password' : 'db_user_password',
        'database.transactionIsolationLevel' : 'READ_COMMITTED',
        'database.initialiseSchema' : 'true'
]
```

**RPC User**

```
rpcUsers = [[ user: "rpc_user", "password": "rpc_user_password", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
```

Ok, I'm adding my node's `node.config` (it's part of Corda TestNet, and it's deployed on Google Cloud):

```
baseDirectory = "."
compatibilityZoneURL = "https://netmap.testnet.r3.com"
emailAddress = "xxx"
jarDirs = [ "plugins", "cordapps" ]
sshd { port = 2222 }
myLegalName = "OU=xxx, O=TESTNET_xxx, L=London, C=GB"
keyStorePassword = "xxx"
trustStorePassword = "xxx"
crlCheckSoftFail = true
database = {
    transactionIsolationLevel = "READ_COMMITTED"
    initialiseSchema = "true"
}
dataSourceProperties {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx:xxx/postgres"
    dataSource.user = xxx
    dataSource.password = xxx
}
p2pAddress = "xxx:xxx"
rpcSettings {
    useSsl = false
    standAloneBroker = false
    address = "0.0.0.0:xxx"
    adminAddress = "0.0.0.0:xxx"
}
rpcUsers = [
    { username=cordazoneservice, password=xxx, permissions=[ ALL ] }
]
devMode = false
cordappSignerKeyFingerprintBlacklist = []
useTestClock = false
```

Comment: Hi Adel, that's exactly what I was asking but I tried to run the nodes using rpcUsers property and got an error " Unknown property: rpcUsers".

Comment: Can you paste your `node.conf` file?

Comment: I updated my answer as well and added a sample `node.conf`.